# Multiple command for bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, openshift

I want to assign a variable after executing the set of commands
The first command is to get into the shell of the openshift pod. Then cat a file and assign that to a variable outside the openshift container.

I tried it like this

```
check=$(oc rsh pod << EOF
cat /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/check.pub
EOF)
```

It gives me an error

```
bash: warning: here-document at line 41 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

Comment: this is a warning, not an error per se -- did you check the content of the variable `check`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the second EOF needs to be on a line by itself:

```
check=$(oc rsh pod << EOF 
cat /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/check.pub 
EOF
)
```

Comment: Indeed, and, generally, _no_ trailing characters, not even tabs or spaces, are allowed. In this special case - end-of-file with respect to the _command substitution_ (`$(...)`) - the delimiter is still _recognized_ (i.e., the code works), but a _warning_ is issued.  Note that the warning was introduced in Bash v4; Bash 3.x quietly accepts the code in the question.